# Global search custom field not searching

Tags: community, custom-object, global-search, global

In my object two date fields (Filling date,Issue date) are there,when i go and search in global search of the filling date value it is showing results perfectly(Refer image) but,[image]

when i search the second date field i.e.,Issue date values in global search , it is not showing results,eventhough i added that field in search fields(Refer image)
[image]

Only filling date value is searching,not issue date values(Refer image)
[image]

Comment: check FLS for community profile for that field

Comment: Field level security visible only

Comment: is 'Issue Date of Parent' a formula field?

Comment: No, it is a custom date field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One work-around you could use is to have a rule (Workflow/Process Builder) copy the Text of the Date to a Custom Text Field. This Field will be searchable, so you will be able to find the your Record.